# React Functional Component and scope

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have an issue with a React Functional Component which is a video player. I need to call a function called `onEnded` from the video players `ended` event. The function is a callback that is being passed into the component, as well as a number value `videoId`. Here's my code:

```
const handlePlayerReady = (player) => {
    playerRef.current = player;

    // You can handle player events here, for example:
    player.on('waiting', () => {
      videojs.log('player is waiting');
    });

    player.on('playing', () => {
      videojs.log('player is playing');
    });

    player.on('ended', () => {
      console.log('exit video container :', videoId);
      onEnded(videoId);
    });

    player.on('dispose', () => {
      videojs.log('player will dispose');
    });
  };
```

I am convinced that this is to do with scope because if I call `onEnded(videoId)` from outside of the event handler, then it is called and the `videoId` is the value I expect. If I run it as it is above, the `videoId` value is `undefined` but the callback is called.

The only other thing that it could be is that the `handlePlayerReady` is called before `videoId` is set.

Can anyone shed some light on why the method is called but the parameter is not read?

Comment: There's really nowhere near enough information here to answer any of your questions. We have no idea what `videoId` is, what any code is that sets `videoId` and when that is run, or even when `handlePlayerReady` is called.

Comment: Where is `videoId` ever set?  I would expect this to produce an error when trying to use a variable that isn't defined.  Can you update this to a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates what you're trying to describe?

Comment: Thank you. I worked it out. Was to do with event listeners and how to handle them with hooks.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out that the `handlePlayerReady` function was being called before the `videoId` prop value was being set so the event handlers were set in stone.

I had to trigger the event listeners using the `useEffect`. The full component is here:

```
// import React from 'react';
import { useEffect, useState, useCallback, useRef } from 'react';
import videojs from 'video.js';
import VideoPlayer from './videoPlayer';

export default function VideoContainer({videoId, isVisible, onEnded, filename}) {

  const playerRef = useRef(null);
  
  // useEffect(() => {
    
  // }, []);

  // let thisVideoId = videoId;

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('id for video container: ', videoId);
  }, [videoId]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(isVisible){
      const player = playerRef.current;
      listenPlayerEvents();
      // player.requestFullscreen();
      player.play();
      // DEBUG // exitVideoContainer();
      return () => removePlayerListeners();
    }
  }, [isVisible]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const player = playerRef.current;
    if(player == null) return;
    player.src({src: `./assets/video/${filename}`, type: 'video/mp4'});
  }, [filename]);

  const videoJsOptions = {
    autoplay: false,
    controls: false,
    responsive: true,
    fluid: true,
    // sources: [{
    //   src: './assets/video/trip_to_the_us_grant.mp4',
    //   type: 'video/mp4'
    // }]
  };

  const listenPlayerEvents = () => {
    // You can handle player events here, for example:
    playerRef.current.on('waiting', () => {
      videojs.log('player is waiting');
    });

    playerRef.current.on('playing', () => {
      console.log('video playing :', videoId);
      videojs.log('player is playing');
    });

    playerRef.current.on('ended', () => {
      console.log('exit video container :', videoId);
      onEnded(videoId);
    });

    playerRef.current.on('dispose', () => {
      videojs.log('player will dispose');
    });
  };

  const removePlayerListeners = () => {
    playerRef.current.off('waiting');
    playerRef.current.off('playing');
    playerRef.current.off('ended');
    playerRef.current.off('dispose');
  };

  const handlePlayerReady = (player) => {
    playerRef.current = player;
  };

  return (
    <div className={`absolute ${isVisible ? 'block' : 'hidden'} w-screen h-screen bg-black`}>
      <VideoPlayer options={videoJsOptions} onReady={handlePlayerReady} />
    </div>
  );
}
```